# rake aborted! ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I installed rails 3.2.3 in my pc but for my new project i need to work in rails 3.0.5 so I installed 3.0.5 version of rails and now when i write any rake command i get the following error

```
rake aborted! ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
```

currently this rake version is installed in my pc rake (10.1.0)

I know the error says everything but im new in ruby and rails. So i don't understand what to do. I googled it but most of the solutions ask to update rails

Answer (score 0):

> I know the error says everything but im new in ruby and rails. So i don't understand what to do. I googled it but most of the solutions ask to update rails

That's unfortunately the best solution. You are using a very old version of Rails that was based on some conventions of the time. Rake has changed and 10.0 is no longer compatible with  that Rails version.

You should install a previous rake version. 0.9.0 should be sufficient.
In your Gemfile set

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.0'
```

then run `$ bundle`. Make sure you will prefix every command with

```
bundle exec
```

such as

```
bundle exec rake -T
```

instead of

```
rake -T
```

otherwise the script will fall back again using the most recent version of Rails on your machine.

For your reference, the reason of the error is probably caused by the [`documentation.rake`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.5/railties/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake) file that at the very beginning it includes a deprecated `rake` file, removed in [GH-1301](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/1301).

Keep in mind that, assuming the app will then run, your first goal should be to upgrade your app. In fact, if you try to use it as it is, it's likely you will encounter so many other incompatibilities.

That was fairly simple to debug (assuming you have a reasonable knowledge of Ruby and Rails internals), but others may be harder or even impossible to fix forcing you to nothing else than upgrade.